# Read plist file during runtime

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I have included a plist file in my program and called it locally

```
     NSString *plistpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pli" ofType:@"plist"];
     NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistpath];
     NSArray *cont = [dict allValues];
```

I want my program to read the file when I update it manually(not by program), add or delete data from the plist file, during runtime rather than having to stop my execution and start running it again. Is there ay way i can achieve this?

Please Help

Comment: And what's your issue? Also, you can't write into `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, meaning you have to copy it the first time elsewhere where you should be able to edit it (update).

Comment: @Larme I don't want to stop the program and re-run it everytime i add a value in the plist file manually. I want to know if there is any ay by which it will detect the changes itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to save your data in .plist file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// get documents path

  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// get the path to our Data/plist file

 NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myData.plist"];
                            NSError *writeError = nil;

 NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:yourDictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];

        if(plistData)
          {
             [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
              NSLog(@"Data saved sucessfully");
          }
          else
          {
              NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", writeError.localizedDescription);

          }
```

Read plist from the bundle and get Root Dictionary out of it

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myData.plist"];


 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
    {
      plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myData" ofType:@"plist"];
    }

 NSDictionary *resultDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to learn about OS based `dispatch_source_*` calls (gcd) for with you can monitor folder/file changes.

Start from here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1385630-dispatch_source_create

If you want to see a working example you can look at the source of https://github.com/tblank555/iMonitorMyFiles

*PS: Changing NSBundle objects by hand is a bad practice. It seems like what you really need is a settings view, just saying.*